# How to remove the hash from the URL when using react-scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-scroll

I'm using react-scroll and I would like to know if it's possible to remove the hash from the url, currently I have a couple of views in a single page, those views have their own ID in order to use react-scroll, so, I just wanted to know if there is an option to remove it, I saw a cople of solutions like

```
<script>
function removehash(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        history.replaceState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
    });
}
</script>
```

but didnt work, can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState). Normally when you change what a user's looking at, you run a pushState so that the URL changes to "what it would be if the user wanted to go directly to what they're now seeing". Just make sure not to indiscriminantly push: use replaceState when it makes sense so the user's history doesn't get flooded with "the same URL".